# How to open modules in Python having or starting with # in their name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, python-import, python-module

This question is based on the assumption that you don't want to rename your modules and want to have # in their name.So how do you import these modules in Python? I tried using single/double inverted commas but still get a SyntaxError.

```
from "#Calc" import *

from '#Calc' import *
```

Please advise.

Comment: If you made these modules you should probably just rename them so they don't start with '#.'

Comment: Module name is a Python identifier. Python identifiers cannot contain a #. You cannot do what you want.

Comment: Why do you name your modules like that in first place? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id40

Answer (score 1):

You could try [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) or `calc = __import__('#Calc')`

But the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) Style-Guide recommends not to use Upper-Case Letters or Symbols.

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.